# setTimeout dynamic delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have global `setTimeout` function as follow:

```
myTimer = function(){
  var timer;
  this.set = function(saveFormCB) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      saveFormCB();
    }, 10000)
  };
  this.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  return this;
}();
```

Above will delay saveFormCB() execution 10 second if I do like below:

```
myTimer.clear()
myTimer.set(function () {
  saveFormCB()
});
```

Some component need faster execution than 10 second, say 5 second. So I need dynamic delay for myTimer function. I did below but not working:

```
myTimer = function(a){
  var timer;
  this.set = function(saveFormCB) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      saveFormCB();
    }, a || 10000)
  };
  this.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  return this;
}();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

`myTimer` execute on input event. Everytime no typing, `myTimer` will be executed and the value will be saved to db (with saveFormCB() function) after 10 second `myTimer` was executed

Comment: Shouldn't you `clearTimeout` instead of `clearInterval` ?

Comment: I don't know. This is for autosave form. clearInterval for clearing the setTimeout but haven't executed and setTimeout for new value

Comment: Assuming you passed a number through the `a` variable this should work. Please provide more code or examples as to how you would execute these functions.

Comment: @brod on input event. Everytime no typing, myTimer will be executed

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your iife is being passed `window` as this, so your myTimer is a reference to the window object and set and clear are globals. Test it. If you go into strict mode, you'll get an error.

What you need is not to make it an iife and make it a constructor, and make it `Timer` just as a matter of convention for constructors

```
Timer = function(a){
  var timer;
  this.set = function(saveFormCB) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      saveFormCB();
    }, a || 10000)
  };
  this.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  return this;
};

var myTimer = new Timer(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't think this code is right.

```
myTimer.set(function () { //new function
  saveFormCB() // calling another function inside this function.
});
```

Instead you can just do this

```
myTimer.set(saveFormCB); //directly pass the function call as a parameter.
```

Now coming to making your timer dynamic. Use the below code.

```
 myTimer = function(){ //remove the parameter here
  var timer;
  this.set = function(saveFormCB,Timer) { //add the timer parameter here
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      saveFormCB();
    }, Timer || 10000)
  };
  this.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  return this;
}();
```

And you can execute it like below,

```
myTimer.set(saveFormCB,3000);
```

Comment: It should be `myTimer.set(saveFormCB)` (remove the brackets)

Comment: @jasonscript Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with wrapping saveFormCb. Actually, the way you have it now, saveFormCb will be passed an argument in Firefox, how much delay there was from the time you requested it. That could have bad side effects on other cases where you intended it to be called without any arguments

Comment: Nothing wrong in the way he already has it, But I just pointed out it is not necessary to do so, Also function call without arguments sholud be  like `saveFormCB()` and not `saveFormCB` right?? let me know If my knowledge is wrong

Comment: That's exactly what I pointed out, your suggestion is not exactly equivalent to what the OP was doing. Also, as I commented on my answer, `this` is set incorrectly in the original post (and in your answer)

Comment: You are absolutely right about the `this` being window instance. Also I dont understand why my suggestion was not equivalent to what OP was doing. But still I agree with you. Also checked your answer and I think thats the right one.. +1 for you. thanks for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're not passing a variable into the closure properly.

```
var THERE_SHOULD_BE_A_VALUE_HERE = 5000;
myTimer = function(a){
  var timer;
  this.set = function(saveFormCB) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      saveFormCB();
    }, a || 10000)
  };
  this.clear = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
  return this;
}(THERE_SHOULD_BE_A_VALUE_HERE);
```

But this is not dynamic which is what you want right? The simple solution would be to add a to the set function in mytimer and then execute it with a second parameter

```
 myTimer = function(){
      var timer;
      this.set = function(saveFormCB,a) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          saveFormCB();
        }, a || 10000)
      };
      this.clear = function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
      };
      return this;
    }();
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
myTimer.set(function(){console.log('Hello World')},5000)
```

Comment: Note that `this` is pointing to window in that case, see my answer which allows you to create multiple independent timers